# Microsoft Visual Studio 2022 - Stop All and Any Formatting

Tags: visual-c++, formatting, visual-studio-2022

**I absolutely hate that Microsoft Visual Studio reformats my code**. I'm constantly fighting with it. Over the years I've tried several versions and numerous settings but nothing stops the blighter. It insists on reformatting everything and as a general rule making a mess.

Automated re-indenting and alignment when applying brackets\braces or pasting in C#, Razor, HTML and JS files are my main pain points.

Seriously, it's a productivity issue and it drives me nuts . I know this question has been asked many, many times before, but surely, in this day and age there's a way to simply turn it ALL off?! Please tell me somewhere out there somebody knows how to do this.

**Reference**: Using Microsoft Visual Studio 2022 17.3.0. Community Edition. No plugins (Resharper etc.). All settings reset to defaults (using Tools > Import and Export Settings Wizard, Reset all Settings)

**Side note**: I know other IDEs exist but some projects just need MSVC and I'm not looking to change editors. Although I'd accept answers which recommend a plugin guaranteed to solve the problem.

Comment: **Tools -> Options -> Text Editor** provides the bulk of the control here. You can try "All Languages -> Tabs -> Indenting - None" to start.

Comment: Yeah. Tried it all. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/options-text-editor-csharp-formatting?view=vs-2022#indentation-page . Just want to turn it off as it's a big mess.

Answer (score 1):

This will not fully solve the issue but hopefully will already help so I'll post it as an answer.
Even without Resharper there are a lot of options under Text Editor settings and this allows you to control (to a certain extent) how the IDE formats your code, but sometimes it's option A or B and not "both" or "any". This means depending on what you type formatting will happen anyway, however as most people always format in a particular way, spending some time tweaking this is worth so once it is done it will be much less painful. Also the vast majority of settings is per specific language and not in the same structure, which does not make it easier. For `C# - Braces` for example, here's where to start:

`Settings > C# > Code Style > Formatting > New Lines: all "Place open brace..." settings`

Regarding the other main pain point (`pasting`) these should help:

**HTML**
`Settings > Text Editor > HTML > Advanced: Set "Format on paste" to False.`

**JS**
`Settings > Text Editor > Javascript/Typescript > Formatting > General > Automatic Formatting: Uncheck "Format on paste"`

**C#**
`Settings > Text Editor > C# > Code Style > Formatting > General: Uncheck "Automatically format on... (all options to disable all)`

Comment: Thanks and understood. I suspect I'm asking for a solution which doesn't exist - I think formatting is just badly implemented. I've been tweaking these settings for 5 years + and never found a good set of defaults that work. I tend to work around the problem using  a combination of undo (ctrl+z), manually re-applying my formatting, or ctrl + d to reformat the whole document, or just giving up and leaving it. At this stage I want to turn it off and stop it interfering.